# Change in entropy when mixing water at different temperature

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility

Suppose two amounts of water of the same mass, but with different temperature, are mixed. Then the [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy) of the hot water decreases, but the entropy of the cold water increases due to heat transfer.

But how is the entropy of whole system increased? And how is this irreversible?

(Or am I getting the concept of entropy wrong?)

Comment: Related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37861/  and http://physics.bu.edu/~redner/211-sp06/class-engines/class25_secondlaw.html

Comment: @count_to_10 there is doesn't say how is the Entropy of whole system has increased.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The bottom line is that hot water loses heat at high temperature, giving a small negative entropy change while the cold water gain heat at low temperature resulting in a high entropy change. The net entropy change is positive. We can explicitly see this:

At any instant, the infinitesimal change in the entropy of the system is
$$dS=\frac{dQ_H}{T_H}+\frac{dQ_C}{T_C},$$
where $dQ_H<0$ and $dQ_C>0$ are the heat exchanged by the hot and cold water respectively. The corresponding temperatures are $T_H$ and $T_C$. Since
$$|dQ_H|=|dQ_C|\equiv dQ>0,$$
we can write
$$dS=dQ\left(\frac{1}{T_C}-\frac{1}{T_H}\right)=dQ\left(\frac{T_H-T_C}{T_HT_C}\right)>0.$$
At any instant the temperature of the hot water is greater than the temperature of the cold water. So the $dS$ above is always positive and the process is irreversible at any intermediate state.

Comment: Please explain: Why is it necessary to say the masses of the hot and cold waters are the same when defining dQ?

Comment: @user93982 That was a slip! You don't even need the masses to be equal.

Answer (score 10):

To get the entropy change for a system experiencing an irreversible process, the first step is to **forget entirely about the actual irreversible process** and, instead, devise a reversible process that takes the system between the same initial and final equilibrium states. That is what is meant by $dq_{rev}/T$. The reversible process that you devise does not have to bear any resemblance whatsoever to the actual irreversible process.  In the case of the hot and cold masses m of water, the initial state is Th and Tc, and the final state is (Th+Tc)/2.  The reversible process I would devise would be to separate the two initial masses, and then subject each of them separately to a continuous sequence of constant temperature reservoirs running from their initial temperature to (Th+Tc)/2, letting the heat transfer with the reservoirs occur very gradually for each.  The entropy change for the hot mass would be $$\Delta S=mC\ln{\left[\frac{(T_h+T_c)/2}{T_h}\right]}$$where C is the heat capacity of the water.  Similarly, for the cold mass, 
$$\Delta S=mC\ln{\left[\frac{(T_h+T_c)/2}{T_c}\right]}$$
So, for the combined system, $$\Delta S=mC\ln{\left[\frac{(T_h+T_c)^2}{4T_hT_c}\right]}$$
This entropy change is always greater than zero.

Comment: can you show that this is greater than zero mathematically?

Comment: @lucky-guess The arithmetic mean of two numbers is always greater than their geometric mean.

Answer (score 7):

From a strictly by-the-formulas point of view, entropy change is heat transfer divided by the temperature over which the heat transfer occurs.  The heat transfer is clearly the same for both volumes but positive for the cold volume and negative for the hot volume (heat flowed out of the hot volume and into the cold volume) but the average temperature over which it occurs is lower for the cold volume (it went from cold to equilibrium) than it is for the hot volume (which went from hot to equilibrium), so the positive heat transfer is divided by a smaller number than the negative heat transfer, therefore the total entropy change is positive.

From a statistical mechanics point of view, there are clearly more configurations of the water molecules resembling the final state than there are for the initial state.  In the initial state, molecules of different average energy are bound in separate volumes, while in the final state, all molecules have the same average energy and they are free to move anywhere within the total volume.

Intuitively, consider that it would be extremely unlikely for the final state to spontaneously evolve to the initial state.

And in the most general sense, entropy is a measure of how close a system is to equilibrium. The initial state is not at equilibrium and the final state is.

Answer (score 3):

Mixing the water at different temperatures is an irreversible process, in that once you mix them, you get an average temperature for the system and you can't undo the process, without doing work on the system.

Entropy Postulate: If an irreversible process occurs in a closed system, the entropy S of the system always increase.

This is because before you mixed the water, you could have done work with the high temperature water, after mixing you can do less work because you have less energy to use.

Answer (score 3):

Entropy is a tricky concept at first but with some rigorous thought it becomes more and more intuitive.

When you mix hot and cold water they become inseparable in a closed system (closed to energy....we can still change the volume). Imagine putting a label on every single water molecule of the cold water and then picking them all out after you mix them with the hot water.  You would have to supply quite a bit of energy in order to sift through all the molecules and separate them. (The second law applies to "closed" systems - which means to apply this correctly we cannot add energy to a system and thus sifting through and separating the molecules breaks the second law as it implies opening the system)

There are a couple ways to see that the entropy  of the total system increases.

The first is simple: each volume of initially separated water has a greater volume to explore after mixing.  Therefore the entropy goes up.  This argument is best applied for 2 systems of water at the same temperature.

The second realization is that the maxwell-boltzman (MB) distribution of molecule speeds is asymmetric.  When you mix two MB distributions of different average speeds the average speed of the resulting mixture is bounded by the average speeds of the two initial mixtures.

However, the number of molecules slower and faster in the mixture will not add geometrically.  The asymmetric distribution will be of a different "shape" than the two initial distributions. Therefore the entropy increases after mixing two temperatures

Im not entirely sure but i think you are thinking of entropy as adding vectorally or being conserved.

I.e. the entropy of hot + entropy of cold = entropy of (hot + cold).....this is not true in general